# Chrome doesn't scale images proportionally below first rendered size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to scale images to the height of their parent which has a percentage height of its parent. This works as expected except in Chrome where the image won't scale its width proportionally once the height is reduced below the size at which it was first rendered. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
</div>
```

and the css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    height: 70%;
    background-color: red;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzyvagina/vJxHy/)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `width` property fixes this:

```
img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm not sure why this happens, but I'm guessing that making the width always at auto would fallback to the original width when the image is scaled down (this doesn't happen in most cases I've tried, but a certain combination might trigger it to happen that way). Not sure if it's by design or not, but I'll go ahead and try to report this somewhere.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJxHy/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't fix the problem for me. I'm on Chrome 27

Comment: Then apparently it's a bug - I'm on Chrome 29 (dev) and the fiddle works for me, so apparently they fixed it.

Comment: The project I'm working on is due before 29's release so any ideas for a temp fix?

Comment: Sorry, not that I can find ):

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: block; to make Chrome scale the image below the rendering-size:

```
    display: block; 
min-height: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
width: auto;
```